# Jenkins Admin Password not being accepted

Tags: docker, jenkins

I've installed jenkins in a docker container using this command:

> docker run --restart=unless-stopped --name devonejenkins -p 8080:8080
>   -p 50000:50000 -v /mnt/storage/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins

When i browse to the installation at `localhost:8080` I get the screen where Im supposed to enter the admin password.

I then cut and paste the password that's located in `/var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword` and i get an error saying that it is not the correct one.

Not sure what to do about this,
Chris.

Comment: Is it a clean container or are you using a custom : **/var/jenkins_home/** ?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to run the command as docker logs <container-id/name>
And scroll down, you'll get to see this kind of output,

[Output screen of Docker Logs on container ID for downloading Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjF3e.png)

use ctrl+c or ctrl+insert and paste into the jenkins setup

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you ran the command above without the -d argument, the password should be in your terminal's standard output. If you do run it with the -d argument, you will need to run:

```
docker logs jenkins
```

to view the output from the container.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved this myself.  I appears the hyper-v VM im running ubuntu 18.04 on does not support the clipboard.  The key i was pasting in wasn't the key i thought it was.

So, fixed.  Thanks to all that helped.